# Angular datatables - add row in a dynamic column table

Tags: angularjs, datatables

I have a datatable table with a variable columns number and I need to add rows to it.

That's how I set the columns:

```
var columns = getColumnsName();
columns.forEach(function(column, index){
    dtColumns.push(DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(index).withTitle(column));
});
```

This only works when I don't put a `<tr>` inside `<tbody>`. If I put a `<tr>` inside `<tbody>`, I got the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at _fnGetRowElements (jquery.dataTables.js:3021)
    at HTMLTableRowElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.js:2428)
    at jquery.js:144
    at Function.map (jquery.js:467)
    at jQuery.fn.init.map (jquery.js:143)
    at _fnAddTr (jquery.dataTables.js:2427)
    at loadedInit (jquery.dataTables.js:1307)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.js:1332)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:374)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.js:139)
```

Note that if I can't put a `<tr>`, I can't place a `ng-repeat` to repeat my data inside `<tbody>`.

I seems that I'm getting the above error when I have a `<tr>` inside `<tbody>` without enough `<td>` inside it. Supposing I know how many columns I have and put this exactly number of `<td>` inside `<tr>`, I don't get this error...

How can I add rows to table in this case?

---

**EDIT**

As asked, here goes the HTML:

```
<table dt-options="ctrl.dtOptions" dt-columns="ctrl.dtColumns" dt-column-defs="ctrl.dtColumnDefs" datatable="ng">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please add your html markup, too. It may help with solving the issue.

Comment: Added at question edit.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following after injecting $timeout.

```
    $timeout(function(){

      var columns = getColumnsName();
      columns.forEach(function(column, index){
         dtColumns.push(DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(index).withTitle(column));
      });
    });
```

Comment: Didn't work :( . Got this message: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null`.